Using PyROOT with Anaconda. C system headers must be installed
I want to install ROOT and use it in python to execute a script using import ROOT.
I used:
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create -c conda-forge --name root_env root
conda activate root_env

to install ROOT.
I then selected the root_env environment in Pycharm:

This throws the following error:
C system headers (glibc/Xcode/Windows SDK) must be installed.
fatal error: module map file 'module.modulemap' not found
Warning in cling::IncrementalParser::CheckABICompatibility():
  Failed to extract C++ standard library version.
Warning in cling::IncrementalParser::CheckABICompatibility():
  Possible C++ standard library mismatch, compiled with _LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION '1'
  Extraction of runtime standard library version was: ''
Replaced symbol at_quick_exit cannot be found in JIT!
Module Darwin not found.
Failed to load module std
<<< cling interactive line includer >>>: fatal error: module file '/tmp/root-feedstock/miniforge3/conda-bld/root_base_1719007212029/work/build-dir/lib/Darwin.pcm' not found: module file not found
<<< cling interactive line includer >>>: note: imported by module '_Builtin_intrinsics' in '/opt/anaconda3/envs/root_env/lib/_Builtin_intrinsics.pcm'
Failed to load module _Builtin_intrinsics
Failed to load module _Builtin_intrinsics
Failed to load module std

 * Break * segmentation violation


Things I have already tried:

uninstall brew (environment variable clashes)
reinstall anaconda distribution
install anaconda with brew
reinstall xcode tools

How can i use PyROOT?
